# Who stole half my CPUs

Tags: linux

I had a look at /proc/cpuinfo today and instead of 8 cpus there are now 4. Who stole these four? I mean if someone steals something from you they are required to pay damages. If they steal your voice from your apartment they go do gaol. If HR sends bad half truths information illegaly to other company, they are subject to the massive GDPR fines.

Someone stole half my CPUs and the police don't care.

Dajana Rohde evil HR @ here.com

Comment: I really want to say "I Did", but in fact, I did not. Generally Hyperthreading presents each extra thread as an extra CPU. did you recently disable hyperthreading in the BIOS? that would account for the change.  just out of curioursity, what did you tell the police?

Answer (score 3):

### Intel stole them! ... sort of.

I believe that your distro have implemented the Intel mitigations for the MDS attacks. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/mds.html

So the offenders are Intel. You should make a note of this in the police report. Mind you the police do nothing, and if you don't have two witnesses you can do whatever you like without fearing any justice. Its just how things are. The rules and laws don't apply. You can twist things, however you like without fear of punishment.